# Unable to invite Instagram sandbox users

Tags: instagram

I've set up a developer account for Instagram. I'm trying to invite other users for testing, but I don't seem to have the function available to me. From another screenshot I saw, there's supposed to be a box under the admin account that would allow me to invite people, but I don't see that option. I've tried both Firefox and Chrome and disabled my adblocker with no change.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_ID>/roles/roles/ and at the bottom there are instagram test users and ADD button

Comment: The Instagram account is not SSO connected to Facebook. The app does not exist as an app in Facebook, only in Instagram. Unless there's a way to push from Instagram to Facebook?

Comment: Instagram dedicated API is deprecated and closed already that's why nothing works. So switch to Facebook.

Comment: Wow, ok, I didn't realize. You'd think the actual developers who are actually coding our app would've brought this up to me months ago, but no. Wow... Thanks for pointing this out.